# Enums defined in a class is a static nested class?

Tags: java, enums, inner-classes

For an enumeration defined in a class, like

```
class OuterClass {
    public enum Method {
        GET,
        PUT,
        POST,
        DELETE;
    }
}
```

Is the enumeration a static nested class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)? It seems to be the case judging from the syntax used to refer to it. Or is it a non-static nested class (an inner class)?

Comment: Enums are always static.

Comment: Yes @shmosel, thanks - but I would qualify that by saying `nested enums are always static`, because the `static` qualifier only applies to members inside classes, be they fields, methods, or classes.

Comment: I don't follow. Are you suggesting nested enums are not members?

Comment: @shmosel FreshAir is simply saying that `static` only applies to class members, so only **nested** enums are `static`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The JLS says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> An enum declaration specifies a new enum type, a special kind of class type.

So it looks like the word from Oracle is that enums are classes.

If you declare an enum inside another class, then yes, it's an inner class.  And enums are always static, so *yes*, it's fair to call an enum a static inner class (or nested class) when it's declared in another class.

Answer (score 4):

As per [§8.9 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> An enum declaration specifies a new enum type, a special kind of class type.
>
> [...]
>
> A nested enum type is implicitly `static`. It is permitted for the declaration of a nested enum type to redundantly specify the `static` modifier. [...]

Answer (score 3):

The generated bytecode for the `enum` declaration is as follows:

```
// compiled from: OuterClass.java
public final static enum INNERCLASS ...
```

So yes, `enum` is a *static nested class* in this case - confirmation in the [JLS.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Comment: Oleksandr, thanks for the answer. But what does `.../OuterClass$Method .../OuterClass Method` and the `.../` syntax mean? Does this mean other OuterClass methods are on the same level as `INNERCLASS`? I couldn't find this syntax in the JLS or JVM specs.

Comment: It was just a bytecode name of the innerclass `Method` (`oleksandr/pyrohov/OuterClass$Method`). I cut off the part of it with `.../` intentionally, as I wanted to focus your attention only on the following part of the bytecode: `public final static enum INNERCLASS`.